# How to center a button in the remaining space beside a centered video

Tags: css

I want to make this layout with CSS:
[image: Centered video with red button]

The `<video>` (its aspect ratio and size may change) should be centered vertically and horizontally in the container with the black background (the size of the container may also change). The `<button>` should be centered in the remaining space on the right side of the `<video>`. If there is no space left for the button, it should overlay the `<video>`.

What I currently have is this:

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
video:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 16px;

  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 200px; width: 700px;">
  <video src="https://static.videezy.com/system/protected/files/000/019/696/pointing_blue.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

but I don't know how to center the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords:

- Add elements (`.button-spacer`) on both sides of the video to claim the width needed for a button.
- Center and space everything evenly using [flex layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
- Use `absolute` positioning on the button to keep it on-screen even if there isn't enough room next to the video.

```css
.player {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;

  background-color: black;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  align-self: center;
}
video:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.button-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-width: 50px;

  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  background: maroon;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="player" style="height: 120px; width: 400px;">
  <div class="button-spacer"></div>
  <video src="https://static.videezy.com/system/protected/files/000/019/696/pointing_blue.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
  <div class="button-spacer">
    <button></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flex (again) and a pseudo can help you without position :

```css
div {
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

video {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 -50px;
}

video:focus {
  outline: none;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  margin: -100px;
}

button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid white;
  margin: -100px;
 
}
```

```html
<div style="height: 200px; width: 700px;">
  <video src="https://static.videezy.com/system/protected/files/000/019/696/pointing_blue.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

Comment: It works if the container is wider than high, but if it is higher than wide, the button is squeezed. It would be better if the button would then overlay the video.

Comment: You may play with negative margins , snippet updated

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the problem by editing it from `right: 16px;` to `right: 9%;` in the `button{}` line 4.
I hope it fixes your problem

```
<style>
div {
  background-color: black;
  position: relative;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

video {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
video:focus {
  outline: none;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 50%;

  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  border: 5px solid white;
}
</style>
<div style="height: 200px; width: 700px;">
  <video src="https://static.videezy.com/system/protected/files/000/019/696/pointing_blue.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
  <button></button>
</div>
```